# Linker problems in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors

Alright, so this is getting very very annoying. I have an unmanaged VC 2010 ++ solution with 9 projects in it, from which two of them are projects that output static libraries for remaining 7 test projects to use. In 6 of those 7 I don't get a single linker error, while in the 7th that is configured exactly the same like those 6, I currently get 12 linker errors and I fail to see what am I doing wrong (If I'm doing something wrong at all).

I've tried:

- adding those two libraries directly into project using `Project -> Add-> Existing files`
- linking them in with `#pragma comment(lib,"libname.lib")` directive
- adding references in `Project Properties -> Common Properties-> Framework and References`
- adding them in linker additional dependencies (I checked to see if the path is correct 10 times already)

Yet I can't get this to link for hours already (and yes, project build order is set as it should be). I never had such problems with VS 2008, and I'm hoping I will not need to roll back to VS2008 to get this solved, because I really don't have enough time to mess with setting up Visual Studio again.

So, any suggestions?

http://i47.servimg.com/u/f47/14/27/08/40/window10.png

http://i47.servimg.com/u/f47/14/27/08/40/window11.png

EDIT:

```
  file = fz_open_fd(fd);
  error = pdf_open_xref_with_stream(&p_xref, file, NULL);
  fz_close(file);
  p_outline = pdf_load_outline(p_xref);
  ....
```

Comment: http://i47.servimg.com/u/f47/14/27/08/40/window12.png

http://i47.servimg.com/u/f47/14/27/08/40/window13.png

remaining two screenshots

Comment: pls post the code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to guess.  But I see a source file named "cppwrapper".  Which makes it likely that you are wrapping something that's written in C.  Which makes it likely that you have to tell the compiler explicitly that this is C code and not C++ code.  Like this:

```
extern "C" {
   #include "foo.h"
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, but functions in lib are declared as extern "C" ? Yet this somehow worked. Got some problems with LIBCMT.lib afterwards, but I resolved it using /NODEFAULTLIB. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just saw that even if I had added extern "C" to the functions themselves their names were still mangled.. :O

Answer (score 0):

add `$(OutDir)` to your library paths

Comment: like this:

http://i47.servimg.com/u/f47/14/27/08/40/window14.png

?

Still the same ^^

Comment: yes... like this. and what about linker - additional dependences?